# Create a Windows VPN Connection from the cmd line

Tags: windows, vpn, command-line-interface

Does anybody know if its possible to create a Windows PPTP VPN connection from the command line for XP/Vista machines?  This will allow me to do somethings via Group Policy.

Regards

Comment: Are you talking about a pptp VPN connection?

Comment: Sorry - yes its a PPTP VPN with XP/Vista Clients.

Comment: RASDIAL is what you're looking for -- [see my question, answered by John Rennie](http://serverfault.com/questions/29513/vpn-client-connect-disconnect-via-command-line-in-xp). If this helps you, upvote his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll really enjoy the [Connection Manager Administation Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739464(WS.10).aspx) if you want to create a maintainable method for distributing VPN connection information. The CMAK also lets you do some neat things like running a script when the VPN connection starts.

You can use this tool to create a program to generate an EXE that automatically configures client computers with a "connection" to your VPN server. We typically deploy it onto client computers using startup scripts with a registry-based versioning mechanism to cause computers to install new versions if we deploy them.

Comment: +1 This is the best way to go. Use the http://www.isaserver.org/img/upl/vpnkitbeta2/cmak.htm tutorial and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the details are (OS version and type of firewall),  but NETSH should do the trick for you.  See if this helps:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configure-Windows-2008-Advanced-Firewall-NETSH-CLI.html

Comment: I have managed to solve my problem by using the information in the following link:-

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/System_Utilities/Remote_Access/VPN/Q_23274656.html