# Script to setup VPN connection for users

Tags: vpn, powershell, scripting

I am trying to make a simple script that will setup a VPN connection in Windows for the different remote users that need to be on our VPN.

I was going to go with powershell as I couldn't find a way to do this with netsh and found this:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name "Test1" -ServerAddress "10.1.1.1" -PassThru
```

However I tried it and it does not appear to work on Windows 7, looked it up and see that it is only for Windows 8 and up / Server 2012 and up.

Is there any Windows 7 equivalent? Or a way to get this to work on Windows 7?

Comment: Please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614465/establish-a-vpn-connection-in-cmd and http://serverfault.com/questions/58469/create-a-windows-vpn-connection-from-the-cmd-line

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that I was able to get this to work.

1) Use Group Policy Preferences. Its real easy to configure however, it does not allow much customizations. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772449(v=ws.11).aspx

2) Copy the Phonebook file to the local computer (using GPP file copy) http://thesbsguy.com/2010/06/09/rasvpn-phonebook-in-win-7-server-2008/