# Connecting to Microsoft VPN during MDT deployment

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, deployment, wds, mdt-2010

So I've finally got the deployment almost perfect. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to connect automatically to a VPN using Microsofts Connections. I tried just adding a custom task "Run Command Line" and adding a rasdial statement but not luck. Would a batch file work better? The ideal scenario is it would finish the deployment. Connect VPN. Join Domain. Updates. Reboot. Everythings ready to go. Any ideas / help / pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this figured out. It was an issue with how I was copying files via MDT deployment.
I finally got the syntax right and just ran a batch script that copied a RAS phonebook to the %allusers% location to allow every one access to it.

Answer (score 1):

A batch file would be the best way to do this. Looks at this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/29513/vpn-client-connect-disconnect-via-command-line-in-xp) by John Rennie. That would give you the basics. The [CMAK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753977(v=ws.10).aspx) would also have some tools to accomplish this.